# Write office plugin to add new fields to the meeting request

Tags: plugins, ms-office, outlook-addin

Is there a way to write an office plugin to add new fields to the New Meeting Request section in Outlook? for example, I want to add a new field for Agenda...

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable:
For this purpose you should add User Property to your Outlook.MeetingItem:

```
 Outlook.MeetingItem item = //get or create your item here;
 if(item.UserProperties["Agenda"] == null){
     Outlook.UserProperty property = item.UserProperties.Add("Agenda", olText);
 }
 property.value = "Your agenda"; 
 item.Save();
```

This code will add Agenda property to your meeting item.

Now if you want to display it you should go with [Custom View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb207115.aspx) or [Custom TaskPane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [Form Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386301.aspx)

Comment: The question is whether this data will also be sent to the receiving mail client? Probably not, or?